# Mongoose - Update Balance for each ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, foreach, mongoose

I'm trying to update multiple User Balances if Matching ID is present.

I'm using Mongoose, this is how my saved document looks like:

```
    { tokens: [],
      profile: { gender: '', location: '', website: '', picture: '' },
      __v: 0,
      balance: 0,
      userWalletID: '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE',
      password: '$2a$10$JRs/hyiStyhcZzHBwFnhmulKX0vTqlNMTGdxJjDdCSD0Bufe7K6wC',
      email: '111111111111111111111@11111111111111111.com',
      username: '111111111111111111111',
      createdAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:11 GMT+0300 (EEST),
      updatedAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:17 GMT+0300 (EEST),
      _id: 57268553ea2d6bb50c9d4069 }
    { tokens: [],
      profile: { gender: '', location: '', website: '', picture: '' },
      __v: 0,
      balance: 0,
      userWalletID: '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC',
      password: '$2a$10$cCo5gQgqcRpQW9Dl/Q.48uJEQCaOpJOLY8LVpQxoQFZ6nUqQD8lEC',
      email: '2222222222222222222222222@222222222222222222.com',
      username: '2222222222222222222222222',
      createdAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:38 GMT+0300 (EEST),
      updatedAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:38:44 GMT+0300 (EEST),
      _id: 5726856eea2d6bb50c9d406a }
    { tokens: [],
      profile: { gender: '', location: '', website: '', picture: '' },
      __v: 0,
      balance: 5645645,
      userWalletID: '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL',
      password: '$2a$10$tL96HqPIAi6q8XnI3z4Bc.dX88fTYQXsTt.UFWJQn4k6ZdDFOZLe2',
      email: '33333333333333333333333@33333333333333333333333.com',
      username: '33333333333333333333333',
      createdAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:39:03 GMT+0300 (EEST),
      updatedAt: Mon May 02 2016 01:39:09 GMT+0300 (EEST),
      _id: 57268587ea2d6bb50c9d406b }
```

Next, I used User.find() to get all userWalletID and run a get call to get a JSON OBJ containing all Wallet Info for all userWalletID inside my DB.

```
  User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {console.log('Could not find Wallets in DB');}
      var allDBWallets  = []; var allOBJWallets = [];

    docs.forEach(function(address) {
      console.log(address);
      allDBWallets.push(address.userWalletID);
    });

    for( var iteration in allDBWallets){ 
        bitgo.wallets().get({ "id": allDBWallets[iteration] }, function callback(err, wallet) { 
          if (err) { console.log(err); }
          allOBJWallets.push(wallet);
          jsonfile.writeFileSync(allConfirmedBalance, allOBJWallets, {spaces: 3});
        });
    }

  });
```

I get back an array with 3 objects.

```
  [
     {
        "_id": "5726858f42929c5c066825b6cc7f9d96",
        "id": "2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8zA12U9YnJU3fSxoCq857uMcFon6ViZdYMSeXbeVUGtGkBCasmE3SGdJVRr4ui1V8TzsmM7K6eKikSi9gZQiJXoVumGTnU",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "031ec65814f7e46e274a78671f6ed2b945c386e378160b19613ce8ba555e793635",
                    "chainCode": "a046f6f6ea9fd06974b333e87a483c9c3cbdeb41c0e56c8f21a6954f9f95e387",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEnS2CtwqrMNKDnpsogbX1tukjM2xWyW1PttVLSEVgDiJq7bWh6esAQWeQ9oGNR56RHqwzKLCzzneM6DGq91v8sA9DAJbUbtm",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "027f30812a8f33ffeb44515d0fe9cc99041c2369f407ecc537d492d34da48c29d2",
                    "chainCode": "4f493067187019f78a773e3e559c699b98c0e82a53cbf76cf9ba5db8103062a0",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58402,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcF6cBQfmTER34dwShTVu6x2h24nxhHxMX3jAHCP9DJYuLcHABvaMeaBcSMdcte8mhAMnCcBCypK5iGe6H33aUH8JWbstSKP9",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "02ec33597217f00f1ad5689b0abbfd01d850c921d4560d1333f52f9f70eea2aafd",
                    "chainCode": "37b746ccdf38587d6a943f8007ef9e3012f52c73079f53c094f446cd43f9bb4f",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 310488966,
        "instantBalance": 310488966,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 310488966,
        "confirmedBalance": 310488966,
        "spendableBalance": 310488966,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 310488966,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 0
     },
     {
        "_id": "5726857642929c5c066825819a872925",
        "id": "2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcH2AHKRsNyEv4euymBzY8P52NzeodZBBvG8zPtpLeEJmjD8xevZRrDLCyCr4TjmavB9TuAw69bDH3TkKNPyEQ2UBVrGg8uVq",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "038c20add130bf5d79fc1debc658e8866f5c69962efc15350941d18cc3b88c025f",
                    "chainCode": "f8e61f519f8e5363b24fe19912a25c90395a9189f59517d5c888c2b2eaefe4ba",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEkcMvj2xtGSMhQzAys7EMV4gvqporNz5kSkzuqt3x25cnpvYWyR24y38WYij7eLr3xSQsBo7TBHWR27b5QZTrj5sVq5MMBVa",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "037e26f5594705a05a49e63dbd7eb98e0fb56d0f26b584c8e4fcdb15efd0239d62",
                    "chainCode": "984f19d3ae866a97a1b3a0bad1abf2a9aa77dbf50465180dee0cf8a8b73089c8",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58401,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcGdVpPbFpvi37Ziteqj4JY3uEoV6XijMAk62Pgs2jK3bRPPVjKg4AtwbZ6xiMMHD56oHCdGQwqtWNZgwSWefw9edex9aJ9KC",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "03b323e0b6ebb0cbb845be13c5a090c4648de18c090382e899e66c389c0f6451fc",
                    "chainCode": "d1a6e364a4b44764190148e725a8c584583743d31df2d06439b70016e19799b5",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 1003135000,
        "instantBalance": 1003135000,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 1003135000,
        "confirmedBalance": 1003135000,
        "spendableBalance": 1003135000,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 1003135000,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 0
     },
     {
        "_id": "5726855c0cb29c5b060918484524d6d9",
        "id": "2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE",
        "label": "123labeling",
        "isActive": true,
        "type": "safehd",
        "freeze": {},
        "adminCount": 1,
        "disableTransactionNotifications": false,
        "private": {
           "keychains": [
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcFcyTCTTNVmYcAmPJ2yRJanFPv9To7n1wk5cZmgUpzY16pAz9m6XriziHnk6c4Y2Hov9HJSmWPSHdmSLn9KNBLMr5Qi29HGN",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "032536e93aa4cd5feb0706d118b6ecf695d26544c00f92a2fb36ef9208ee216821",
                    "chainCode": "6c4dbaed05b8a09d2d64c3688e3fb53f12e62ef64b70ad808a700830e2063bb2",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub6GiRC55CRvMEhQVtxhHwwpmG7NVyjT1SUuyYXfafsRDW4XoYRwzPp6Af5vY83hLN8vaFCzk9FdtUqdeXoQbS7fXNJU3eFYPnU1bfkjimsT4",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "035d12105eab700c637ca9fbbea066beca88c6603f90f98c07a9e5b84713d6ff20",
                    "chainCode": "5670e6ede3379f33cc635981c7fbe9255c3f69a5e4868e5491e42bf3d5fb380a",
                    "depth": 5,
                    "index": 58400,
                    "parentFingerprint": 2966462100
                 }
              },
              {
                 "xpub": "xpub661MyMwAqRbcEZBgr8PUbKfGBaQ98GFp2wGdR6vDwTAzruGenMnn3PqDo9MMmzSsF8dFWgUfUUV1Yor2ErVrohBNHj9Ug81ih7VAohfnEQu",
                 "path": "/0/0",
                 "params": {
                    "pubKey": "024f7b2f85a3e0b859c4bdb975f9953973de4806300b2148afec66fb610af380a7",
                    "chainCode": "014ce166076a6045fb5a88fa4a51052d13c5449a4367d030e0f6bc058a9d0191",
                    "depth": 0,
                    "index": 0,
                    "parentFingerprint": 0
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "canSendInstant": true,
        "permissions": "admin,spend,view",
        "admin": {
           "users": [
              {
                 "user": "56f9e3b2cd8f2e5906530948fe1af2d2",
                 "permissions": "admin,spend,view"
              }
           ]
        },
        "tags": [],
        "approvalsRequired": 1,
        "spendingAccount": true,
        "pendingApprovals": [],
        "balance": 2205867000,
        "instantBalance": 2205867000,
        "spendableConfirmedBalance": 2205867000,
        "confirmedBalance": 2205867000,
        "spendableBalance": 2205867000,
        "sent": 0,
        "received": 2205867000,
        "unconfirmedSends": 0,
        "unconfirmedReceives": 0
     }
  ]
```

Each JSON OBJ `"id": "2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC"`, matches one DB userWalletID. I tried to write something on my own by adding all userWalletID to an array and passing it as a getter like so:

```
    jsonfile.readFile(allConfirmedBalance, function(err, obj) {
      var getAllWallets = [];

      obj.forEach(function(obj){
        getAllWallets.push(obj.id);
      });

       console.log(getAllWallets);
[ '2N3qPHp7bNaL4hiztrzZCzCywryKUzb5aLE',
  '2My1FGBG6erNXfzeGXg5DXnLk2PWxhpk9SL',
  '2N2oG4nBJZU19Aks3MLvHqDKMXePmHhbEjC' ]

      User.model('User').update({"playerWallet" : {"$in":getAllWallets}}, {"$set": {"balance" : spendableConfirmedBalance[i]}}, {active:false} , {multi: true} , function(err,docs) {
        console.log(docs); 
      });

    });
```

But failed miserably,

Bare in mind that spendableConfirmedBalance[i] is just as an example as I have no clue how to do update for each individual matching ID their respective balance ....

What is the best way to update each mathing IDs balance: 0, with their "spendableConfirmedBalance": 2205867000 ?

Thank you for your help and awesome advice's !

Comment: You cannot update multiple documents and set different values in one query. You need to update each user individually.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm going to try to save it inside the iteration before i save to JSON and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in one call. It works great, thank you Molda for your pointing out Mongo way of doing things. Kudos !!!

```
var listWallets = function() {

    User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {console.log('Could not find Wallets in DB');}
        var allDBWallets  = []; var allOBJWallets = [];

      docs.forEach(function(address) {
        // console.log(address);
        allDBWallets.push(address.userWalletID);
      });

      for( var iteration in allDBWallets){ 
          bitgo.wallets().get({ "id": allDBWallets[iteration] }, function callback(err, wallet) { 
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            allOBJWallets.push(wallet);

              for (var walletIteration in allDBWallets) {
                if(allDBWallets[walletIteration] == wallet.wallet.id){
                  console.log(wallet.wallet.id, wallet.wallet.spendableConfirmedBalance);

                    var conditions = { userWalletID: wallet.wallet.id }
                      , update = { $set: { balance: wallet.wallet.spendableConfirmedBalance }}
                      , options = { multi: false };

                    User.update(conditions, update, options, function callback (err, numAffected) {
                      console.log(numAffected);
                    });
                }
            }

            jsonfile.writeFileSync(allConfirmedBalance, allOBJWallets, {spaces: 3});
          });
      }

    });
};
```